# Поменять порядок следования соседних цифр на противоположный

Tags: int

Всем привет!

Мне дали такое задание, цитирую:

> Дано целое число. Образуйте новое, в котором порядок следования соседних цифр будет противоположен.

Как вы могли уже догадаться, проблемы с пониманием задачи (но если вы сразу поняли, то мое уважение). Итак, если у кого-то есть идеи, то буду рад их прочитать.

Пока накину своих мыслей. Пусть мы ввели целое число n = 1234.
Тогда нам нужно, чтобы соседние цифры поменяли свой порядок следования. Причем нам нужен именно порядок, соответственно, неважно, расположены ли они друг за другом или с разрывом в несколько символов. Тогда изменим порядок цифр 1, 2 и 3, 4. Получим 2143. Но тогда порядок у цифр 2, 4 и 1, 3 будет тем же, который был в числе n, тогда меняем эти цифры местами: 4321. В этом числе мы видим, что какую бы мы пару соседних цифр не взяли, в новом числе эта пара будет отражена (12 -> 21, 23 -> 32, 34 -> 43). Что думаете?

Спасибо всем заранее)

Comment: это задание на программирование или на сообразительность? что-то очень запутанная формулировка. если на программирование, то могли бы просто сказать: поменяйте порядок цифр числа на обратный.

Comment: @SergFSM это задание на программирование) Дано в качестве "лабораторной работы". Там вообще несколько заданий, мне попалось именно это. Оно, как по мне, наиболее непонятное

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что в итоге оказалось. Приведенный мною алгоритм обработки числа оказался ошибочным. Правильным же будет алгоритм, который будет переводить число 1234 в 2143. То есть каждые элементы пары двух соседних цифр буду меняться местами. Это и есть весь алгоритм. Спасибо всем, кто отозвался и пытался помочь с вопросами со своей точки зрения. Тема закрыта.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

просто для разнообразия придумал такой способ развернуть целое число не прибегая к операциям со строками:

```
n = 12345
f = lambda x: [x] if x<10 else f(x//10) + [x%10]
n = sum(j*10**i for i,j in enumerate(f(n)))
print(n)  # 54321
```

Answer (score -1):

> Образуйте новое, в котором порядок следования соседних цифр будет противоположен.

Я думаю, что вы правильно поняли задачу. Можно и по-другому трактовать, то есть *порядок последовательности соседних цифр между каждым числом*.
Пример, `1 2 3` - > `3 2 1`

Если вы хотите реализовать решение задачи на *Python*, то предложу следующее:

```
n = list(input()) 

count = 0

while count < len(n) - 1:
    n[count], n[count + 1] = n[count + 1], n[count]
    count += 1
print(int(''.join(n)))
```

Кстати, данная задача похожа на *метод сортировки 'пузырьком'*, только соседние цифры меняются между собой в случае, если первая больше второго:

```
a = list(map(int, list(input())))
N = len(a)
for i in range(N - 1):
    for j in range(N - i - 1):
        if a[j] > a[j + 1]:
            a[j], a[j + 1] = a[j + 1], a[j]
 
print(a)
print(int(''.join(list(map(str, a)))))
```